# AWS Elastic Transcoder Endpoint cannot be resolved

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I'm working on a project that requires video to be transcoded and thumbnails extracted through use of AWS Elastic Transcoder. I have followed the api to the best of my abilities and have what seems to me correct code. However, I still get an error with `NameResolutionFailure` thrown and an inner exception saying that `The remote name could not be resolved: 'elastictranscoder.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'`My code is:

```
        var transcoder = 
                      new AmazonElasticTranscoderClient(Constants.AmazonS3AccessKey, 
                                Constants.AmazonS3SecretKey, RegionEndpoint.USWest2);
        var ji = new JobInput
        {
            AspectRatio = "auto",
            Container = "mov",
            FrameRate = "auto",
            Interlaced = "auto",
            Resolution = "auto",
            Key = filename
        };

        var output = new CreateJobOutput
        {
            ThumbnailPattern = filename + "_{count}",
            Rotate = "auto",
            PresetId = "1351620000001-000010",
            Key = filename + "_enc.mp4"
        };

        var createJob = new CreateJobRequest
        {
            Input = ji,
            Output = output,
            PipelineId = "1413517673900-39qstm"
        };

        transcoder.CreateJob(createJob);
```

I have my s3 buckets configure in Oregon and added policies to make the files public.

Comment: The code looks correct and almost identical to my working version. Although it's a long shot I would try a different region. I am using USEast1. If that doesn't work make sure you can ping the remote name.

Comment: I created new buckets and pipeline in USEast1 region and apparently uploading to s3 buckets does not work either, same exception. I tried to ping the remote name `lectioinput.s3.amazonaws.com` and the requests timed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my virtual machine was not connecting to the internet, which is why the `nameresolutionfailure` was thrown. Everything is fine now.